# the range cannot be deleted error in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word file and I want to delete some pages in it. I use this Kutools codes for deleting

```
Sub DeletePagesInDoc()
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim xPage As String
    Dim xDoc As Document
    Dim xArr
    Dim I, xSplitCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xDoc = ActiveDocument
    xPage = InputBox("Enter the page numbers of pages to be deleted: " & vbNewLine & _
            "use comma to separate numbers", "KuTools for Word", "")
    xArr = Split(xPage, ",")
    xPageCount = UBound(xArr)
    For I = xPageCount To 0 Step -1
        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, xArr(I)
        xDoc.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Delete
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Some pages are deleted but some pages aren't. The word gives me this error `The range cannot be deleted.` Why I get this error?

Comment: Just guessing here: When you delete a range the rest of the ranges are redefined to fill the hole the deleted range occupied. You need to refresh the remaining ranges in each loop. Also, single-step through the code might prove useful

Comment: The range may contain something that's protected. When this happens, STOP the macro and look at the Word document to see what's in the selection.

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes, something protected in it but how am I doing it unprotected. When I am doing right click on the table, **delete table** option is disable. How do I enable it?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing more about the table/document. What could certainly be a problem is if a table is split across pages. Is that the case, here? And if/when this happens is the intention to delete the entire table?